# WebBrowser "steals" KeyDown events from my form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, webbrowser-control

I have a `WebBwoser` inside a `Form`, and I want to capture the Ctrl+O key combination to use as a shortcut for a menu item. My problem is that if I click on the `WebBrowser` and I press Ctrl+O, an Internet Explorer dialog pops up, instead of doing what my menu item does. I have my `Form`'s `KeyPreview` property set to `true`. Also, I added an event handler for the `KeyDown` event, but it stops getting called after I click the `WebBrowser`. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should solve your problem. It disabled the accelerator keys of the web browser.

```
webBrowser1.WebBrowserShortcutsEnabled = false;
```

You might want to explore whether you need `IsWebBrowserContextMenuEnabled` as well.

The following may also solve your problem if you need some accelerators keys to be active on the browser. However, this approach requires something to capture the focus. `MessageBox.Show()` and `dialog.ShowDialog()` can do the job

```
    private void DoSomething()
    {
        webBrowser1.PreviewKeyDown += new PreviewKeyDownEventHandler(webBrowser1_PreviewKeyDown);
    }
    private void webBrowser1_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, PreviewKeyDownEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.O)
        {
            menuItem.PerformClick();
            // MessageBox.Show("Done");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Well, is that the only possible solution? I want the user to be able to do other stuff like searching by pressing Ctrl+F.

Comment: +1 you beat me by network speed, my browser hangs when I'm trying to find the link on MSDN :(

Comment: You can capture the `PreviewKeyDown` on the `webBrowser` as shown in my edited answer above.

Comment: If the webBrowser1.WebBrowserShortcutsEnabled property is true, I received two calls to PreviewKeyDown. Setting it to false only generated one per real key press.

Comment: That `Webbrowser`!. Always with the joke.

Answer (score 2):

You could override the ProcessCmdKey method:

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Meassage msg, Keys keyDaya)
{
    //Trap for Key down 

    return true; //false if you want to suppress the key press.
}
```